# How does one reset the dataloader in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I was trying to reset the dataloader manually but was unable. I tried everything here https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-could-i-reset-dataloader-or-count-data-batch-with-iter-instead-of-epoch/22902/4 but no luck. Anyone know how to reset the data loader AND also have the suffle/randomness of the batches not be broken?

Answer (score 12):

To *reset* a DataLoader then just *enumerate* the loader again. Each call to `enumerate(loader)` starts from the beginning.

To not *break* transformers that use random values, then *reset* the random seed each time the DataLoader is initialized.

```py
def seed_init_fn(x):
   seed = args.seed + x
   np.random.seed(seed)
   random.seed(seed)
   torch.manual_seed(seed)
   return

loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(...., worker_init_fn = seed_init_fn)

while True:
   for i,data in enumerate(loader):
      # will always yield same data
```

See `worker_init_fn` in the documents:

https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader

Here is a better example:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/5059#issuecomment-404232359

Comment: What do you mean by *transformers*? You mean random samplers? These don't yield the same samples every time you iterate through the Dataloader. I don't see why you need to reset the seed in a typical scenario where you simply want different samples each epoch.